Decoding input from transaction using contract ABI
I have a transaction in which I know a swap occurred when a wallet sold a token through Uniswap. I am trying to extract the ETH amount the wallet received for this swap. I have pulled the entire transaction from the hash. With this I was able to pull the input from the transaction and decode the input using the ABI. That input further had more input which I believe contains the ETH amount swapped for as a parameter. I am not able to decode this input using the same contract ABI. Does anyone know how to do this?
Here is the transaction object I am getting from the hash which contains the input to be decoded:
---------------------------------------------------------
Transaction:  {
  accessList: [],
  blockHash: '0xcfe13ce901db505346206727662b281bd4272d80befd4e455f47ab55911b2a63',
  blockNumber: 19715682,
  chainId: '0x1',
  from: '0x9ae6c4196E8ca4aEE7bFCA0E2A767019e1fDbe26',
  gas: 277647,
  gasPrice: '6715712975',
  hash: '0x2691a1feec999b296b6b5a4e16f531b525afe59554246d23bfe8ccfd580cd495',
  input: '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',
  maxFeePerGas: '8901577448',
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: '8852928',
  nonce: 50,
  r: '0xacee312e2c08370a589b27ef7aa67f184cdd2f238b0087df88afcf6cd0c6a607',
  s: '0x54e7e72dd0ce0d66a8f409e7c21ee2537bddafefae16f73d6e08dceabb6784f3',
  to: '0x3fC91A3afd70395Cd496C647d5a6CC9D4B2b7FAD',
  transactionIndex: 3,
  type: 2,
  v: '0x1',
  value: '0',
  yParity: '0x1'
}
---------------------------------------------------------

Here is the decoded input from above using the contract ABI:
====================================================
Decoded Input: {
  name: 'execute',
  params: [
    { name: 'commands', value: '0x0a08060c', type: 'bytes' },
    { name: 'inputs', value: [Array], type: 'bytes[]' },
    { name: 'deadline', value: '1713846755', type: 'uint256' }
  ]
}
====================================================

Here are the different components inside the input which I attempt to decode using the same uniswap contract ABI:
Components in input 'execute' to decode: [ 'commands', 'inputs', 'deadline' ]
****************************************************
Command 0a08060c
Command in Bytes: Uint8Array(4) [ 10, 8, 6, 12 ]
Decoded Command: null
****************************************************
Input: 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
Decoded Input: null

Input: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000332bce2c361136af0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ac7bf173c0e05a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000a6eba1ed27b1a4ba00b020819264a70133b6e127000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2
Decoded Input: null

Input: 0x000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc200000000000000000000000037a8f295612602f2774d331e562be9e61b83a3270000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000019
Decoded Input: null

Input: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ac0d8da60627788
Decoded Input: null

****************************************************
Deadline Block: 1713846755
****************************************************

Finally, here is the code responsible for executing the printing to the terminal from above:
const printSellTransactionData = async () => {
  const hash = '0x2691a1feec999b296b6b5a4e16f531b525afe59554246d23bfe8ccfd580cd495'
  const tx = await getTransaction(hash);
  console.log("---------------------------------------------------------")
  console.log("Transaction: ", tx)
  console.log("---------------------------------------------------------")
  const contractAddress = tx.to;
  const UniSwapABI = await getABI(contractAddress);
  const input = await getInputFromHash(hash);
  const decodedData = decodeInputUsingABI(input, UniSwapABI);
  if (decodedData) {
    console.log("====================================================");
    console.log("Decoded Input:", decodedData);
    console.log("====================================================");
    const params = decodedData.params;
    if (params.length > 0) {
      console.log("Components in input '" + decodedData.name + "' to decode:", decodedData.params.map(param => param.name));
      console.log("****************************************************")
      for (const param of params) {
        if (param.name === "commands") {
          const cmd = param.value;
        if (cmd.startsWith('0x')) {
          command = cmd.slice(2);
        }
        let commandInBytes = new Uint8Array(command.length / 2);
        for (let i = 0; i < command.length; i += 2) {
          commandInBytes[i / 2] = parseInt(command.substr(i, 2), 16);
        }
        const decodedCommand = decodeInputUsingABI(command, UniSwapABI);
        console.log("Command", command);
        console.log("Command in Bytes:", commandInBytes); // function call followed by parameters?
        console.log("Decoded Command:", decodedCommand);
        console.log("****************************************************")

        }
        else if (param.name === "inputs") {
          const inputs = param.value;
          for (const input of inputs) {
            const decodedInput = decodeInputUsingABI(input, UniSwapABI);
            console.log("Input:", input)
            console.log("Decoded Input:", decodedInput);
            console.log()
          }
          console.log("****************************************************")
        }
        else if (param.name === "deadline") {
          const deadline = param.value;
          console.log("Deadline Block:", deadline)
          console.log("****************************************************")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

